# Error with Quarkus CDI, Injection of inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection, cdi, quarkus

I am attempting to implement dependency injection in a class that is inherited from a base abstract class, and I get the following error: *"**javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException**: It's not possible to automatically add a synthetic no-args constructor to an unproxyable bean class. You need to manually add a non-private no-args constructor to com...ExampleIntegrationProvider in order to fulfill the requirements for normal scoped/intercepted/decorated beans."*

From what I researched, it seems that this happens because classes that are annotated with normal scoped beans such as `@ApplicationScoped` for example, need a non-private constructor without arguments, so that CDI can create a proxy of that class when it is injected in **lazy** mode. I was a bit surprised to find out, as I've never had problems with code like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public UserUseCase(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User findById(long id) { ... }
}
```

Even though Quarkus magically adds a synthetic no-args constructor, how could it overcome the **final** field *UserRepository*? There would be a problem with its initialization  as it needs to receive a value, I imagine it might end up being passed a null value..

Anyway, going straight to my case, here's an example of my current situation, with 3 important base classes and 1 implementation for a "Example" partner:

**PartnerIntegration.java**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PartnerIntegration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

     // other common fields ...
}
```

**PartnerIntegrationRepository.java**

```java
public interface PartnerIntegrationRepository<I extends PartnerIntegration> extends PanacheRepository<I> {
    // common methods ...
}
```

**PartnerIntegrationProvider.java**

```java
public abstract class PartnerIntegrationProvider<I extends PartnerIntegration> {

    protected final PartnerIntegrationRepository<I> partnerIntegrationRepository;

    protected PartnerIntegrationProvider(PartnerIntegrationRepository<I> partnerIntegrationRepository) {
        this.partnerIntegrationRepository = partnerIntegrationRepository;
    }

    // code ...
}
```

And finally the final implementation **ExampleIntegrationProvider.java**:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleIntegrationProvider extends PartnerIntegrationProvider<ExampleIntegration> {

    @Inject
    public ExampleIntegrationProvider(ExampleIntegrationRepository  exampleIntegrationRepository) {
        super(exampleIntegrationRepository);
    }

    // code ...
}
```

The abstract class `PartnerIntegrationProvider` is not annotated with any scope as I did not consider it necessary since it only receives the `PartnerIntegrationRepository` interface and not a concrete repository. But `ExampleIntegrationProvider` receives a concrete repository that is implementing that interface, so I annotated it with `@ApplicationScoped` to be able to inject the concrete repository with `@Inject`. But this generated that error.

I tried creating a public constructor method that passes the null parameter to the parent class, and the error disappeared, but this ends up polluting my code, since I do not want to allow that class to be instantiated without receiving a repository, so I removed the `@ApplicationScoped` and `@Inject` annotations from `ExampleIntegrationProvider` and created that class to produce the instance that will be injected from it:

**ExampleIntegrationProviderBean.java**

```java
@Dependent
public class ExampleIntegrationProviderBean {

    private static ExampleIntegrationProvider INSTANCE;

    private final ExampleIntegrationRepository exampleIntegrationRepository;

    @Inject
    public ExampleIntegrationProviderBean(ExampleIntegrationRepository exampleIntegrationRepository) {
        this.exampleIntegrationRepository = exampleIntegrationRepository;
    }

    @Produces
    public ExampleIntegrationProvider exampleIntegrationProvider() {
        return INSTANCE == null ?
                (INSTANCE = new ExampleIntegrationProvider(exampleIntegrationRepository)) : INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

But the number of partners may grow quickly, I wouldn't like to have to create other classes like this one to produce the instances, and even if it was just one partner, it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution...

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can resolve this in a better way?

Comment: *"I tried creating a public constructor method [...] I do not want to allow that class to be instantiated without receiving a repository"*. According to the CDI spec, the no parameters constructor must be there but it is sufficient to be non-private (See "Unproxyable bean types" in CDI spec). Try adding the constructor as above, but making its visibility package-private.

Comment: Do you need the bean to be `@ApplicationScoped`? If `@Singleton` is fine for you (see here for differences: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#applicationscoped-and-singleton-look-very-similar-which-one-should-i-choose-for-my-quarkus-application), you can use that. `@Singleton` is not a normal scope and so doesn't require a zero-parameter constructor.

Comment: `@Singleton` is definitely an option, in majority of cases you needn't differentiate between having and not having client proxy in place. Otherwise, according to CDI spec, you need to have a no-arg constructor for any beans requiring client proxy. The workaround Quarkus does with generating one for you is only (currently) for a simple scenario without inheritance - it doesn't inspect/change the whole hierarchy,

Comment: I would like to express my gratitude to everyone for their comments. Thanks to them, I now have a clearer understanding of all the ways to solve my problem. I'll be following the suggestions of both Ladicek and Siliarus and incorporating the use of @Singleton in this case.